# Combine the two query ans in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to combine two query answers into single answer.

```
Query 1
------
select value from bindings where id in (31213,31199)

This query returns Answer
-----------------------
TeamA

Query 2
-------

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Number)) FROM OPENJSON('{"value":"6","text":"Apiutharun"}', '$' ) WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(100) '$.value')

This query returns Answer
------------------------
6
```

How to combine both query answers?

```
i Want below Answer
-------------------
TeamA6
```

is it possible to combine two query answers without union operator?

Comment: You want this to return the data from both queries in a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
(select value from bindings where id in (31213,31199)) as Result1,
(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Number)) FROM OPENJSON('{"value":"6","text":"Apiutharun"}', '$' ) WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(100) '$.value')) as Result2
```

Just try this and check

Comment: Now answer is coming like TeamA 6.Is it possible to print the second query answer 6 in next line. i tried char(13).but it is not working. how shall we print the second query ans(json)answer in next line.I tried like this.select
    a.value +
 char(13)+ b.value
from
    (select value from ValueBindings where id in (31199)) a
    cross join (SELECT value = LTRIM(RTRIM(Number)) FROM OPENJSON('{"value":"6","text":"Apiutharun"}', '$' ) WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(100) '$.value')) b

Comment: @Ram im not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

You could select as follows:

```
select CONCAT(value,(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Number)) FROM 
OPENJSON('{"value":"6","text":"Apiutharun"}', '$' ) 
WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(100) '$.value') ) 

from bindings where id in (31213,31199)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use below query and you find the the correct result.

```
Select(select value from bindings where id in (31213,31199))+(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Number)) FROM OPENJSON('{"value":"6","text":"Apiutharun"}', '$' ) WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(100) '$.value'))
```

and result is

```
TeamA6
```